# Retrieve data from Oracle Database to eclipse

Tags: java, oracle, rest

I'm pretty new to this SQL world and Java. 
For my practice, I have a database that has all current/former employee's information.

And I'm trying to create a simple REST service application that returns the employee's name from database in Oracle SQL Developer. 
And if an employee is a 'current employee' it additionally returns their phone number which is next column in a database, if it's former employee it returns "This employee does not exist".

So I connected Eclipse to Oracle Database, after that I am trying to call employee data from my code. How can I do that? and if someone has a simple code that is related to what I am doing it will be helpful for reference! Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I will give simple program as example, and will upto you to learn from it and implement the relevant functionality for you:

```
 //STEP 1. Import required packages
 import java.sql.*;

  public class FirstExample {
 // JDBC driver name and database URL
 static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

 //  Database credentials
 static final String USER = "username";
 static final String PASS = "password";

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Connection conn = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
  try{
   //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

   //STEP 3: Open a connection
   System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

   //STEP 4: Execute a query
   System.out.println("Creating statement...");
   stmt = conn.createStatement();
   String sql;
   sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

   //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
   while(rs.next()){
     //Retrieve by column name
     int id  = rs.getInt("id");
     int age = rs.getInt("age");
     String first = rs.getString("first");
     String last = rs.getString("last");

     //Display values
     System.out.print("ID: " + id);
     System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
     System.out.print(", First: " + first);
     System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
  }
  //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
  //Handle errors for JDBC
  se.printStackTrace();
 }catch(Exception e){
  //Handle errors for Class.forName
  e.printStackTrace();
 }finally{
  //finally block used to close resources
  try{
     if(stmt!=null)
        stmt.close();
  }catch(SQLException se2){
  }// nothing we can do
  try{
     if(conn!=null)
        conn.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
     se.printStackTrace();
  }//end finally try
  }//end try
  System.out.println("Goodbye!");
  }//end main
     }//end FirstExample
```

Please accept and like if you appreciate my gesture to help with my ideas n experience.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done by writing a JDBC Connection to open your database.

How have you connected Oracle to your Eclipse.
May be Documentation from Oracle can Help
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.database.doc/html/gettingStarted/files/gettingStarted.html